# Update the value of an input item based on the value of multiple checkbox controls

Tags: javascript

Here is my Fiddle..  https://jsfiddle.net/sinoobkt/1kd16pgx/1/

If I check the check boxes then the value should get displayed in the input field, if I uncheck a checkbox, its value should be removed from the input field. I  also need to be able remove the values from the input field manually.
Once I click on Clear then All values should get cleared.

```js
function Myfunction(){
  
}
```

```html
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="day" id="1" value="Sunday">Sunday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" id="2" value="Monday">Monday <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" id="3" value="Tuesday">Tuesday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" id="4" value="Thursday">Thursday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" id="5" value="Friday">Friday<br>

Selected Days: <input type="text" name="LastName" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Clear" onclick="Myfunction()">
</form>
```

Comment: Not exactly related, but it looks like you're misusing `input type="submit"`. You actually don't want to submit the form with this button. Use type of button instead. What comes to the question, as it is, it's too broad. You've to try to solve the problem by yourself, and if you'll get stuck, then ask a question.

Comment: Try writing some JavaScript code that we can help you with first.

Comment: You did not try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="day" id="1" value="Sunday" onclick="fillInput(this);">Sunday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" id="2" value="Monday" onclick="fillInput(this);">Monday <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" id="3" value="Tuesday" onclick="fillInput(this);">Tuesday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" id="4" value="Thursday" onclick="fillInput(this);">Thursday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" id="5" value="Friday" onclick="fillInput(this);">Friday<br>

Selected Days: <input type="text" name="LastName" value=""><br>
<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="Myfunction()">
</form>

<script>
function Myfunction(){
  document.getElementsByName("LastName")[0].value="";
}

function fillInput(element){
  if(element.checked) {
    document.getElementsByName("LastName")[0].value= document.getElementsByName("LastName")[0].value + element.value + " ";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementsByName("LastName")[0].value = document.getElementsByName("LastName")[0].value.replace(element.value + " ", "");
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Myfunction(){
  document.getElementById("1").value = "";
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('day');
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            add(this.value);
        } else {
            remove(this.value);
        }
    });
}
function add(value) {
    var textbox = document.getElementById('selectedDay');
    textbox.value += value;
}
function remove(value) {
    var textbox = document.getElementById('selectedDay');
    textbox.value = textbox.value.replace(value, '');
}


<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="day" id="1" value="Sunday">Sunday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" id="2" value="Monday">Monday <br>

<input type="checkbox" name="day" id="3" value="Tuesday">Tuesday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" id="4" value="Thursday">Thursday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" id="5" value="Friday">Friday<br>
Selected Days: <input type="text" id="selectedDay" value=""><br>
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Here, onclick eventlisteners are being added to all the checkboxes, on checking or onchecking it will call the add or remove function respectively which are responsible for adding and removing the Days from the textbox.

And you can make the Clear Button type as reset button and clearly you don't want to perform myFunction() on Clear Button click.